# How to fetch JSON of desired format from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, json, playframework-2.0, c3.js

Using play framework 2.0 and here goes my java code :

```
String queryString="SELECT watchDuration, date(startTime) from SEData";
Query query=JPA.em().createNativeQuery(queryString);
List<Object[]> resultHours = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(resultHours);
renderJSON(json);
```

After browsing for a while, I did try to use Gson, which resulted me with the following output :

```
[[5.0,"Feb 5, 2014"],[6.0,"Feb 6, 2014"],[1.0,"Feb 7, 2014"],[2.0,"May 3, 2017"],[3.0,"May 4, 2017"]]
```

Since I'm fetching this data to plot on a c3.js graph, I need it in the following format :

```
json:[{"value":5, "date":"Feb 5, 2014"},{"value":6, "date":"Feb 6, 2014"},{"value":1, "date":"Feb 7, 2014"},{"value":2, "date":"May 3, 2017"},{"value":3, "date":"May 4, 2017"}]
```

**OR**

```
json: {
     value:[5, 6, 1, 2, 3],
     date: ["Feb 5, 2014", "Feb 6, 2014", "Feb 7, 2014", "May 3, 2017", "May 4, 2017"]
          }
```

How can I achieve the above format retrieved MySQL database?
I doubt if my approach towards Gson is wrong, because the output that I got is not even a JSON I believe. Guide me towards the right approach if I'm not moving towards one. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is gson doesn't know what the properties are called, so it makes an array of unnamed values.

While adding a new class will simplify things, a new class for every return type of a query means a lot of rather useless classes, especially if they are only used for marshalling.

Instead, you can map a name to each list of properties like so

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object> > map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object> >();

ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> dates = new ArrayList<Object>();

for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
    values.add(resultHours.get(i)[0]);
    dates.add(resultHours.get(i)[1]);
}

map.put("value", values);
map.put("date", dates);
```

This produces the desired output:

```
{
    "date": ["Jan","Feb","Mar","April"],
    "value": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Comment: This works like the same way I needed. I had totally forgot about the hashmaps and thank you for opening my third eye :D. I request you to correct the typo error in the following line for future users. Thanks once again. `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object> > map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object> >();`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning a list of Object[] create an object which is typed

```
public class ResultHours {
  public int value;
  public Date date; 
}
```

and then update the `getResultList()`;

```
List<ResultHours[]> resultHours = (List<ResultHours[]>) query.getResultList();
```

I've not tested this but in theory it should work!

Comment: Yes, I will give it a try!